# Solving a system of differential-algebraic equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, systems-of-equations

I am seeking for references around the topic of solving this type of differential equation system :

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \partial_x y_{i+1}(x) = y_{i+1}(x)-y_{i}(x) \\ y_{i+1}(x) = y_i(f(x)) \end{array} \right. $$

where $f$ is not affine.

Comment: Out of curiosity: where does this come from?

Comment: This is more general than delay-differential equations. The locus $f(x)$ can be anywhere in relation to the locus of $x$. Note that even DAE only connect values and derivatives at the one and same locus $x$.